# xCode Round float

Tags: xcode, double, floating

i have number:

3.08

and i use this:

```
NSLog(@"%1.1f", self.test.value);
```

but console output 3.1 not 3.0 i need output 3.0 pls help...

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is rounding up. This might work to force it to round down:

```
NSLog(@"%1.1f", floor(self.test.value*10f) / 10f);
```

Comment: but now my nomber is 1,2,3,4,5 i need 3,1.....3,9 so if my number is 3.19 i want output 3.1

Comment: I added the f to the end to the 10s to make them floats. Sorry about that!